# Validate field in Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and Bootstrap to create a modal dialog. I'm trying to validate `content` field but it doesn't add `error` class to it.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.save-link').on('click', function() {
    $('#linkModal').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
    })
  });
  $('#save_form').on('keyup', function() {
    $("#save_form").validate({
      rules: {
        content: "required"
      },
      messages: {
        content: "required"
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
{{Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'save_form'])}}
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<div class="modal" id="linkModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">
          Add link
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="content-wrapper2">
          {{Form::text('content', null, ['class' => 'required content-wrapper col-md-11 form-control', 'id' => 'content'])}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        {{Form::button('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'save'])}}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
{{Form::close()}}
```

Updated:
I did it in this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('.save-link').on('click', function() {
        $('#linkModal').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        })
    });

    $('#save').on('click', function() {
        customValidate();

    });
    $('#linkModal').on('keyup', function() {
        customValidate();

    });
});
```

```html
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <form class="modal fade" id="linkModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">
                            Add link
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
         
                        <div class="form-group content-wrapper2">
                            {{Form::text('content', null, ['class' => 'form-control required content-wrapper col-md-11', 'id' => 'content'])}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        {{Form::button('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'save'])}}
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
```

and it's working, I don't know why it isn't working with jquery validate.

Comment: Can you confirm you have included the library to use `Form`? What's the current status of your problem? Still need help? What happens when you submit the form? Do you have any errors? Can you delete your `storage/logs/laravel.log` and check to see if any errors come back and include that in your question if so

Comment: There aren't errors in `laravel.log` , yes, I can use `laravel form class`. Now, I'm using this check if input is empty. I couldn't make it work with `jquery validate` using `bootstrap modal`.

Comment: I'm confused. As far as I know, you can't use the `Form` helper class in 5.2 without having included (via composer) the laravel collective e.g. `composer require laravelcollective/html; composer update`. Would you mind showing in your post the raw HTML from your browser or confirm that your form tags are generated as intended? Or do you mean that when you say you are using the laravel form class?

Comment: That's not the problem - from my composer.json - ` "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.2",
        "way/generators":"~3.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec":"~2.0"
    },`.... Would you like to test my code if validation works - this from your answer, I don't think it's laravel issue? :)

Comment: Yep, on second glance it's certainly not the issue, and you would have `Form class not found` like error if it were - I'm about to create a fiddle and inspect your HTML/JS and see what I come up with. If you want me to check over your project - I could do that via a github repo?

Comment: One thing I will say is that after using the collective for forms myself, you may start to find it more of a pain in the ass than just writing out the HTML yourself. One way I do it is to only use the Form helper for the opening and closing tag but even then it doesn't seem to save that much time in the long run, and when you come back to debug, looking at inline array options and stuff like that makes it difficult to understand how the elements were defined.

Comment: Thanks, you could test code from my question, from your answer. I changed my code to add this check and it's not the same and I haven't pushed to git yet because of this issue. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115044/discussion-between-jonathan-and-mistery-girl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm opting to use the parsley jQuery validation library here. Seems to work well and will just require some styling of the error output. You can find the documentation on it at [parsleyjs.org](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-validators-overview). It's the most elegant I can find in the time.

Please [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vq7aq6n/).

I've abandoned the use of the laravel collective form helper. I think it is nice in a certain niche situation but for the most part is overengineering and confusing to read.

The javascript is simple:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#save-link-form").parsley();
  $("#save-link-form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submitted successfully");
  });
});
```

You will want to remove the `e.preventDefault()` and log, and modify it however you wish the form to be submitted, whether by AJAX or, if not - removing the `submit` event callback entirely.

Options for parsley can be put into the form elements themselves using the parsley syntax, but it also overrides default HTML 5 validation as well nicely, so you can use attributes like `required` and `type="url"` without the lame HTML 5 validation taking precedence, but keeping the intuitive HTML 5 syntax.

Comment: Thank you. You are using `parsley` - another way for validation? Won't it possible with jQuery validation. In fact, it doesn't matter which kind of validation has been used, but I just tried to figure out my mistake using jQuery validator.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery validation, if it's this - https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation - then be warned that it's not affiliated with jQuery, it's a third party plugin. The examples I looked at looked so out-dated. I can't be sure whether I'd recommend using it or not without others hinting that it really is actively in use today. Compared to parsley https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/ which looks more actively developed and maintained ;) it's up to you

Comment: Yes, that's what I was talking about - this plugin. I'm not familiar with parsley, but I'll check it. :)

Comment: If I had more time I'd look into the other plugin's docs and see what went wrong but, not being able to see your code clearly and how it reacts makes it a lot more difficult to troubleshoot :(

Answer (score 0):

You can override the jquery validate to use bootstrap `has-error` class

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $.validator.setDefaults({ 
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        } 
    });

  $('.save-link').on('click', function() {
    $('#linkModal').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
    })
  });
  $('#save_form').on('keyup', function() {
    $("#save_form").validate({
      rules: {
        content: "required"
      },
      messages: {
        content: "required"
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Where should I use this and why validator doesn't validate? :)

Comment: It still doesn't add `error` class or `has-error` class